# C++11 to_string() function, where?

Tags: c++, c++11

See the [N3242 Working Draft of C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), chapter 21.5 Numeric Conversions.

There are some useful functions, such as `string to_string(int val);` mentioned but I don't understand how they're called. Can anyone give me an example please?

Comment: You don't understand how they are called with your compiler or you don't understand how they are called generally?

Comment: My compiler is GNU 4.5.2 and it doesn't "see" them in std:: or anywhere else. Yet they're there in _bits/basic_string.h_.

Answer (score 28):

Those functions are in the header `<string>`. You just call them like any other function:

```
#include <string>
std::string answer = std::to_string(42);
```

GCC 4.5 [already supports those functions](http://ideone.com/ffHHK), you just need to compile with the `-std=c++0x` flag.

Answer (score 6):

Sure:

```
std::string s = std::to_string(123);  // now s == "123"
```

These functions use `sprintf` (or equivalent) internally.

Comment: I would of thought they would use stringstream.

Comment: @graham.reeds : No implementation I've seen does, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3):

They are called like any other function:

```
int number = 10;
std::string value;
value = std::to_string(number);
std::cout << value;
```

To call them you will need a C++ compiler that supports the draft recommendations (VS2010 and GCC4+ I think support them).

Comment: OK. Guess I need to upgrade my compiler.

Comment: @catfish_deluxe_call_me_cd no, you don't need to upgrade. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I know this isn't a tech support forum but does anyone else use MinGW to test for this?