# C++11 std::to_string(double) - No trailing zeros

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Today I tried out some new functions of the C++11 STL and encountered `std::to_string`.

Lovely, lovely set of functions. Creating a stringstream object for just one double-to-string conversion always seemed overkill to me, so I'm glad we can now do something like this:

```
std::cout << std::to_string(0.33) << std::endl;
```

The result?

```
0.330000
```

I'm not entirely content with that. Is there a way to tell `std::to_string` to leave out the trailing zeros? I searched the internet, but as far as I can see the function takes only one argument (the value to be converted). Back in 'the old days' with stringstreams, you could set the width of the stream, but I'd rather not convert back.

Anyone encountered this problem before/has a solution? Some StackOverflow searches yielded nothing.

(A C++11 STL reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: @chris: not after the call to `std::to_string`. It returns a string, not a number, and its formatting seems hard to modify.

Comment: @rubenvb, Shoot, I'm not thinking properly, am I...

Comment: "Lovely, lovely set of functions. Creating a stringstream object for just one double-to-string conversion always seemed overkill to me". And then you see why it isn't really overkill -- it's streams that contain all the infrastructure for specifying the format. To get what you want, `to_string` would have to duplicate all that in an equivalent API. Which might not be a terrible idea, but it's not the idea that the committee went with. The reason `to_string` is lovely is that it has no options ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, I can see where they come from. I would just rather have to_string(double/float) not append any trailing zeros on default, and having you use stringstreams if you needed them. But that's getting into matters of preference.

Comment: @Frishert: Yeah. I view these functions as quick-and-dirty outputters, for logging or outputs that are intended to be consumed by machines. For pretty formatting you usually have to take it into your own hands, unfortunately.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The C++11 Standard explicitely says (`21.5/7`):

> Returns: Each function returns a string object holding the character representation of the value of its argument that would be generated by calling sprintf(buf, fmt, val) with a format specifier of "%d", "%u", "%ld", "%lu", "%lld", "%llu", "%f", "%f", or "%Lf", respectively, where buf designates an internal character buffer of sufficient size

for the functions declared in this order:

```
string to_string(int val);
string to_string(unsigned val);
string to_string(long val);
string to_string(unsigned long val);
string to_string(long long val);
string to_string(unsigned long long val);
string to_string(float val);
string to_string(double val);
string to_string(long double val);
```

Thus, you cannot control the formatting of the resulting string.

Answer (score 76):

If all you want to do is remove trailing zeros, well, that's easy.

```
std::string str = std::to_string (f);
str.erase ( str.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos );
str.erase ( str.find_last_not_of('.') + 1, std::string::npos );
```

Comment: Works nearly perfect, except for the corner case where the float/double is an integral number. The result is e.g. `440.`, while some may prefer `440.0` if they're going for pretty output anyway. Nothing that a simple check of the last character won't solve, though.

Comment: correct, this is why I adjusted Marshalls code:

`namespace util {
template <typename T>
std::string
to_string(const T& t) {
    std::string str{std::to_string (t)};
    int offset{1};
    if (str.find_last_not_of('0') == str.find('.')) {
        offset = 0;
    }
    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of('0') + offset, std::string::npos);

    return str;
}
}`

this removes an unnecessary dot also.

Comment: Repeating the last erase with a `.` is sufficient to remove trailing periods 
`str.erase ( str.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos );`
`str.erase ( str.find_last_not_of('.') + 1, std::string::npos );`

Comment: yup, what @ZacharyCanann said!  I ended up with a lot of numbers with "." at the end :)

Answer (score 24):

To leave out the trailing zeros:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::setprecision(8) << std::noshowpoint << double_value;
std::string str = oss.str();
```

Note: `#include <sstream>` and `#include <iomanip>`

Comment: I don't understand why this anwser is not the top one! Thanks Ivan

Comment: Great answer. Just one Q, why do you need to set the precision to 8?

Comment: @Guillaume.P  Probably, because it is not universal. For example, if you use std::fixed, showpoint has no desired effect

Answer (score 16):

`std::to_string` gives you no control over the format; you get the same result as `sprintf` with the appropriate format specifier for the type (`"%f"` in this case).

If you need more flexibility, then you will need a more flexible formatter - such as `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Ok, that was obviously not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks for clearing this up :)

Answer (score 7):

With C++20 we can finally embrace the power of [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)! Which now seems to be supported by all of the mainstream compilers, starting from Clang 17.0.1, GCC 13.1, and MSVC 19.32.

```cpp
std::cout << std::format("{}\n", 0.33);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1ExPjr4eP)

Answer (score 2):

`std::to_string(double)` is defined by the standard to just return the same sequence of characters that would be generated by `sprintf(buf, "%f", value)`. No more, no less, especially no way to tweak the format specifier. So no, there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

With `boost::to_string` you cannot control the format either but it will output something closer to what you see in the screen. Same with `std::lexical_cast<std::string>`.

For a function-like operation with format control, use `str(boost::format("...format...")% 0.33)`.

[What's the difference between std::to_string, boost::to_string, and boost::lexical_cast<std::string>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399064/whats-the-difference-between-stdto-string-boostto-string-and-boostlexic)

Answer (score 0):

A varied solution to the problem since `to_string` doesn't work.
"The Magic Formula" - my CS2400 teacher

```
std::cout.setf(ios::fixed);
std::cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
std::cout.precision(2);

const double x = 0.33, y = 42.3748;
std::cout << "$" << x << std::endl;
std::cout << "$" << y << std::endl;
```

Outputs:

```
$0.33
$42.37
```

any following output you do with decimal numbers will be set as so.

you can always change the setf and precision as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom convert function, remove the tailing zeros if necessary.

```
//! 2018.05.14 13:19:20 CST
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//! Create a custom convert function, remove the tailing zeros if necessary.  
template<typename T>
std::string tostring(const T &n) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << n;
    string s =  oss.str();
    int dotpos = s.find_first_of('.');
    if(dotpos!=std::string::npos){
        int ipos = s.size()-1;
        while(s[ipos]=='0' && ipos>dotpos){
            --ipos;
        }
        s.erase ( ipos + 1, std::string::npos );
    }
    return s;
}

int main(){
    std::cout<< tostring(1230)<<endl;
    std::cout<< tostring(12.30)<<endl;
}
```

---

The input numbers :

```
1230
12.30
```

Compile with `-std=c++11`, then the result:

```
1230
12.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a generic helper function, such as below, which you can repurpose for rounding needs within your C++ project.

```
inline static const string roundDouble(const double input, const int decimal_places)
{
    ostringstream str;
    str << fixed << setprecision(decimal_places);
    str << input;
    return str.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Small code segment to remove trailing zero's - No streams or new Functions

```
double my_double = 50,003; // -> 50.003000
std::string sd = std::to_string(my_double);
for (int i = sd.size() - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    if (sd.at(i) == '0') {
        sd.pop_back(); // Remove if last digit is '0'.
    } else if (sd.at(i) == '.') {
        sd.pop_back(); // Remove dot.
        break; // Break after '.' is removed.
    } else {
        break; // Or break before a digit is removed.
    }
}
// 50.003000 = 50.003
// 50.000000 = 50
```