# What's the difference between std::to_string, boost::to_string, and boost::lexical_cast<std::string>?

Tags: c++, boost, std, tostring, lexical-cast

What's the purpose of `boost::to_string` (found in `boost/exception/to_string.hpp`) and how does it differ from `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>` and `std::to_string`?

Comment: If I recall the history correctly, `boost::to_string` preceded `std::to_string`, as is typically the case. Boost tends to be the playground for stuff before it gets accepted into the standard library. `std::to_string` is new as of C++11.

Comment: @Cyber: I'd suggest you write this as a (partial) answer.

Comment: @CoryKramer, `boost::to_string` might be older, but it's not the same as `std::to_string` and `std::to_string` was not based on it (they just happen to use the same name).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), available since C++11, works on **fundamental numeric types** specifically.  It also has a [`std::to_wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) variant.

It is designed to produce the same results that [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) would.

You may choose this form to avoid dependencies on external libraries/headers.

---

The throw-on-failure function [`boost::lexical_cast<std::string>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) and its non-throwing cousin [`boost::conversion::try_lexical_convert`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.try_lexical_convert) work on **any type that can be inserted into a `std::ostream`**, including types from other libraries or your own code.

Optimized specializations exist for common types, with the generic form resembling:

```
template< typename OutType, typename InType >
OutType lexical_cast( const InType & input ) 
{
    // Insert parameter to an iostream
    std::stringstream temp_stream;
    temp_stream << input;

    // Extract output type from the same iostream
    OutType output;
    temp_stream >> output;
    return output;
}
```

You may choose this form to leverage greater flexibility of input types in generic functions, or to produce a `std::string` from a type that you know isn't a fundamental numeric type.

---

`boost::to_string` isn't directly documented, and seems to be for internal use primarily.  Its functionality behaves like `lexical_cast<std::string>`, not `std::to_string`.

Answer (score 12):

There are more differences: boost::lexical_cast works a bit different when converting double to string. Please consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"

int main()
{
    double maxDouble = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    std::string str(std::to_string(maxDouble));

    std::cout << "std::to_string(" << maxDouble << ") == " << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(" << maxDouble << ") == "
              << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(maxDouble) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Results

```
$ ./to_string
std::to_string(1.79769e+308) == 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(1.79769e+308) == 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

As you can see, the boost version uses exponential notation (1.7976931348623157e+308) whereas std::to_string prints every digit, and six decimal places. One may be more useful than another for your purposes. I personally find the boost version more readable.

Comment: Please do a bit more than just pasting some code. Describe *what* your code does and *how* it does it.

Comment: It is simple the output of to_string() and lexical_cast() for the same double value ;-))

Comment: Those results certainly differ - and that's worth noting.  But it's not obvious to me which result is more "right".