# printf to string for C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

In plain C, we can use `sprintf` to write a formatted string to a preallocated char array. But it has limitations, the most obvious being the need to preallocate a sufficiently large array in advance when you don't always know how long the output will be.

How can we use C-style formatting to create an `std::string` in C++? I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
int x = 10;
std:: string s = astringprintf("pi*%d = %8.3f", x, M_PI*x);
```

Ideally, warnings would be given if the formats don't match the types given - just as `g++` (and `clang++`?) give if you mess up your call to `printf`.

Comment: Note there is [to_string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21519186/1708801) in C++11.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour While that is very useful, you [cannot fine-tune the exact format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686482/c11-stdto-stringdouble-no-trailing-zeros) of the produced string like you can with format codes.

Comment: @CoryKramer sure, I just think it should be mentioned in the question and explained why it is insufficient.

Comment: Agreed. If the OP just wants, e.g. `%f` then `std::to_string` is perfect. It just cannot do `%3.5f` for example.