# Output as currency in C++

Tags: c++, currency, precision

I have a simple C++ command line program where I am taking an input from the user then displaying it as a price, with a currency symbol, commas separating each set of 3 values, a decimal point, and two decimal places which will display even if they are zero.

**Example of what I am trying to achieve:**

```
100 => £100.00
101.1 => £101.10
100000 => £100,000.00
```

**Here is my method so far:**

```
void output_price() {
    int price;

    cout << "Enter a price" << endl;
    cin >> price;
    string num_with_commas = to_string(price);
    int insert_position = num_with_commas.length() - 3;
    while (insert_position > 0) {
        num_with_commas.insert(insert_position, ",");
        insert_position -= 3;
    }

    cout << "The Price is: £" << num_with_commas << endl;
}
```

This is partly working but doesn't show the decimal point/places.

```
1000 => £1000
```

If I change price to a float or double it gives me this:

```
1000 => £10,00.,000,000
```

I am trying to keep things simple and avoid creating a currency class, however not sure if this is possible in C++.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is never a need to create a class like currency, but it is a good idea and not that complicated that you should avoid it.

Comment: Look up the `iomanip` header. More particularly into `std::setprecision`.

Comment: You might fare better in your research if you abstract away the fact that this is currency, and simply search for how to render thousands separators and a fixed number of decimal places, in any arbitrary value. Though, since we're speaking currency, I recommend storing your values as integer pennies (or tenth-pennies), rather than going down the floating-point route.

Comment: I do find it hard to believe your research turned up nothing useful for this. It's a very common requirement.

Comment: `std::put_money` already exists. There's no need to reinvent it and do things like assume the user wants £ as the currency symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical error is here:

```
int insert_position = num_with_commas.length() - 3;
```

The original value of `num_with_commas` could have any number of digits after the dot, including no dot at all; moreover, you have no control over it, because [the format applied by `std::to_string` is fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13686482/335858).

If you would like to continue using `std::to_string`, you need to make a few changes:

- Locate the position of the dot `'.'` character.
- If the dot is there, and the number of characters after it is less than 2, keep appending zeros `"0"` until dot `'.'` is the third character from the back
- If the dot is there, and there are more than two characters after it, remove the tail of the string so that there are exactly two characters after the dot
- If the dot is not there, append `".00"` to string

The rest of your algorithm that inserts dots will work fine.