# c++11 to_string to working with code::blocks -std=c++11 flag already selected

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, stl

this is the code i am trying to compile, got it from another forum somewhere.

```
// to_string example

#include <iostream>   // std::cout

#include <string>     // std::string, std::to_string


int main ()

{

  std::string pi = "pi is " + std::to_string(3.1415926);

  std::string perfect = std::to_string(1+2+4+7+14) + " is a perfect number";

  std::cout << pi << '\n';

  std::cout << perfect << '\n';

  return 0;

}
```

I am getting the error: 
'to_string' is not a member of 'std'

I have read in other forums to select the flags "Have g++ follow the c++11 ISO language standard [-std=c++11]" and i have and it still doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I am using the GNU GCC Compiler
and code::Blocks 12.11

Comment: possible duplicate of [to\_string is not a member of std, says so g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g)

Comment: Works good there. Check your compiler version, does it support C++11?

Comment: I think this is a compiler bug. http://ideone.com/yiIboD

Answer (score 2):

MinGW-w64 added support for the necessary functionality since GCC 4.8, so make sure you are using at least version 4.8 GCC from MinGW-w64.

You can get one from [here](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds), although Code::Blocks should come with a [TDM GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) toolchain which should work if it's the latest (because it's GCC 4.8.1 at the time of writing).

Answer (score 1):

i also encounter this error in codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe(built on 27 Dec 2013).
it seems a bug with tdmgcc4.8.1. maybe the newest tdmgcc whill fixed it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626866/c-elipse-cdt-getting-to-string-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-with-tdm-gcc-6
the reason of above list should be the same as ours.

==============================
The std::to_string functions are guarded by !defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF). MinGW defines this symbol as 1 in its os_defines.h, so you know, we cannot use it in mingw.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to deal with this error is:

```
double piValue = 3.1415;
char piBuffer[8];
sprintf(piBuffer, "%f", piValue);
string pi(piBuffer);
```