# C++ standard alternative to itoa() to convert int to base 10 char*

Tags: c++, windows, string, int, itoa

To convert an integer to base 10 char*

```
std::itoa(ConCounter, ID, 10);
```

ConCounter is an integer, ID is a char*, and 10 is the base

It says that iota is not a member of std and without std it's not declared. I know it's a nonstandard function but I included all the libraries for it and it still doesn't see it.

What is a way to do the above? Any quick one liners?
I've tried the following;

```
std::to_string //it's not declared for me when using mingw, it doesn't exist.
snprintf/sprintf //should work but it gives me the "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'char *'"    error
std::stoi //has same problem as iota
```

Comment: `to_string` is a) in C++11 and b) fixed in newer versions of MinGW.

Comment: BTW, `std::iota` is something rather different than `itoa`.

Comment: @Chris which newer version ? [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) won't compile on MingW g++ (GCC) 4.8.1

Comment: @P0W, I seem to recall it being fixed in the main releases, but it definitely works fine with MinGWBuilds 4.8.1.

Comment: @chris http://i.troll.ws/376fe7ab.jpg

Comment: @P0W, Actually, it might be that MinGWBuilds just applies the patch for you. Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12975602/962089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using roybatty's answer, but I think sprintf should work too. I think when you used it you forgot the format string. It should be:

```
char buf[16];
std::snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", integer);
```

Comment: Everywhere I looked I never was told of the "sizeof(--)" part. It seems that part makes it work. Thank you!

Comment: @nurtul you need it if you use `snprintf`, you don't if you use `sprintf`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
#include <sstream>

int i = // your number
std::ostringstream digit;
digit<<i;
std::string numberString(digit.str());
```

Comment: I added this and I get a "invalid conversion from 'constant char*' to 'char*'" error

Comment: It is because I removed the string part and just did ID = digit.str().c_str(); Which is why I was getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is also "strtol" function : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: `strol` does the opposite than what was wanted

Comment: Oh, sorry %) A thought it was "atoi" in the question.