# C++ Function was not declared in this scope error

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, scope

I am compiling a code, but I seem to get an error, even as I examine my code, I find it weird that I'm getting this error.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "2A";
    int n = stoul(s, nullptr, 16);
    cout << n << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and in the command line, I'm typing `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`, I'm using `-std=c++11` because the function `stoul` is from `C++11` according to this page [stoul](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul).

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:8:30: error: 'stoul' was not declared in this scope
  int n = stoul(s, nullptr, 16);
                              ^
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Compiles fine with gcc 4.7.3. Are you sure you have support for it?

Comment: Probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g/12975602#12975602

Comment: @aizen92 Also compiles fine for me with gcc 4.8.1.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I tried the same code on ideone, and it wokred. It seems to be a problem from my side