# clang 3.4.1 no member named 'to_string' in namespace 'std'

Tags: windows, c++11, netbeans, mingw, clang

I've been trying for hours to get c++11, llvm/clang, and netbeans working on windows. I'm pretty much stuck here. I can't get clang to see the to_string method. After diving into the basic_string header files I notice there are some #ifdefs before to_string is defined

```
#if ((__cplusplus >= 201103L) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99) \
     && !defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF))
```

In Netbeans, I can control-click _GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF and notice its defined as 1 and control-click doesn't work for __cplusplus and _GLIBCXX_USE_C99, so I'm assuming they're undefined.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Also here is the build info && source code if it helps.

```
clang++ -v   -c -g -w -I../SFML/include -I../SFML/src -I../boostInclude -I/C\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include -I/C\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include-fixed -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/CLang-Windows/System/SPString.o.d" -o build/Debug/CLang-Windows/System/SPString.o System/SPString.cpp
clang version 3.4.1 (207424)
Target: i686-pc-mingw32
Thread model: posix
Selected GCC installation: 
 "c:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple i686-pc-mingw32 -S -disable-free -main-file-name SPString.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -v -g -coverage-file "C:\\Users\\IZACK_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\SPString-929e91.s" -resource-dir "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\LLVM\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.4.1" -dependency-file build/Debug/CLang-Windows/System/SPString.o.d -MT build/Debug/CLang-Windows/System/SPString.o -MP -I ../SFML/include -I ../SFML/src -I ../boostInclude -I C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/CMinGWlibgccmingw324.8.1include -I C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/CMinGWlibgccmingw324.8.1include-fixed -w -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fno-dwarf-directory-asm -fdebug-compilation-dir "C:\\SynapseCpp\\SynapseCore" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -vectorize-slp -o "C:\\Users\\IZACK_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\SPString-929e91.s" -x c++ System/SPString.cpp
clang -cc1 version 3.4.1 based upon LLVM 3.4.1-rc2 default target i686-pc-mingw32
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/CMinGWlibgccmingw324.8.1include"
... bunch of irrelevant 'nonexistent directory' ...
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 ../SFML/include
 ../SFML/src
 ../boostInclude
 c:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++
 c:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/mingw32
 c:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/backward
 c:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.4.1\include
 c:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.4.1\../../../include
 /mingw/include
End of search list.
System/SPString.cpp:14:20: error: no member named 'to_string' in namespace 'std'
    string += std::to_string(right);
              ~~~~~^
System/SPString.cpp:21:20: error: no member named 'to_string' in namespace 'std'
    string += std::to_string(right);
              ~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
```

This is the source code:

```
#include "SPString.h"
#include <string>

sf::String& operator +=(const sf::String& left, int right)
{
    sf::String string = left;
    string += std::to_string(right);
    return string;
}

sf::String& operator +(const sf::String& left, int right)
{
    sf::String string = left;
    string += std::to_string(right);

    return string;
}
```

Comment: As I recall this is due to a known bug in MinGW32, it's supposed to be fixed in the 64-bit version but not in the 32-bit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g?rq=1 for more information.

Comment: I did see the bug here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015,  but I assumed it wasn't a problem since the bug is marked as 'RESOLVED FIXED'. Anyways, I applied the patches linked in that stack overflow question and it didn't seem to have any effect :/

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about your sf class, but here's a possible workaround:

```
#include "SPString.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

sf::String& operator +=(const sf::String& left, int right)
{
     std::stringstream stream;
     stream << right;

     sf::String string = left;
     string += stream.str(); 
     return string;
}
```