# g++ include paths on freebsd

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, freebsd

I installed gcc49 on FreeBSD10.1. I am trying to use it for C++11 development. However, every time I'm compiling some C++11 valid code (yes I use `-std=c++11`) that uses specific math functions, it spits out errors, such as

```
error: std::round is not a member of std
/usr/include/math.h
```

For example, here:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::round(10.1) << std::endl;
}
```

So it seems it tries to use the old include files that came with FreeBSD, and not the ones corresponding to the new `gcc` from `/usr/local/lib/gcc49/include`

I tried setting `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib/gcc49/include` with no luck, the system still tries to search `/usr/include` instead.

I saw that this may be a bug in FreeBSD g++,
[Getting GCC in C++11 mode to work on FreeBSD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26832199/3093378)
however even using the `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_C99` as suggested in https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194929
doesn't fix the problem for math functions.

The weirdest thing is that I can compile any other C++11 functions *not from* `<cmath>`, like `std::stol`, but have to use the `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_C99` flag as mentioned in the bug report above.

Any idea how to make g++ fully functional with C++11 on FreeBSD 10.1?

Comment: Do you ask for C++11?

Comment: @Deduplicator yes, I need C++11 support

Comment: @mvw, I tried that, same issue, it seems to not being able to recognize the math part of the C++11 standard library

Comment: @vsoftco `round` is not a member of `std`. Use it without `std::`. It may be a GCC extension.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round it is, since C++11.

Comment: @mvw I just used the latest stable  `10.1/amd64` version (downloaded the installer image from FreeBSD's web site https://www.freebsd.org/where.html) inside a VirtualBox, and installed g++49 with `pkg install lang/gcc49`. I also modified `/etc/make.conf`, tried setting `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH `, but with no luck.

Comment: `gcc` 5 o `gcc 4.9`?

Comment: @black gcc4.9 (it has full support for most of the C++11 stuff, has no problem in compiling the above on any other platform)

Comment: @vsoftco I run into your bug as well. Tricky.

Comment: @mvm, yes, especially since it pretty much makes C++11 un-usable on FreeBSD

Comment: @vsoftco I compared the output after the pre-processing stage using -E from the FreeBSD and from the Debian machine. I found nothing obvious, alas.  Regarding the header file /usr/include/lib/gcc49/include/c++/cmath, the part with `using std::round` is not included in case of FreeBSD. I lack knowledge of the header system to know how to adapt this without breaking other stuff.

Comment: @mvw I think the FreeBSD's C++11 library implementation is just broken...

Answer (score 1):

It works out of box on 10.1, you shouldn't need any hacks. Of course, it only works with -std=c++11, as std::round is only available since 11 standard (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).

```
$ freebsd-version -ku
10.1-RELEASE
10.1-RELEASE
$ cat test.cc
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::round(10.1) << std::endl;
}
$ g++5 -std=c++11 -o test test.cc
$ ./test
10
```

Note: gcc was compiled from ports, package was reported to not work. Probably because packages for 10.1 are at the time of writing compiled on 10.0, which still had c++11 compatibility issues.

Comment: Sorry, I marked the question with gcc5 but I used gcc49. Will try gcc5.

Comment: I just used the latest stable 10.1/amd64 version (downloaded the installer image from FreeBSD's web site freebsd.org/where.html) inside a VirtualBox, and installed g++49 with `pkg install lang/gcc49`. The code above didn't compile. How did you install the compiler? I did not compile it from source.

Comment: I build everything from ports. Packages could be broken because they are built on 10.0.

Comment: thanks, I should then compile the ports. I tested it quickly using `pkg install` because I just wanted to see if my app is portable without issues on FreeBSD. You should mention in the answer that you used the ports, as using `pkg install` doesn't seem to work.