# Getting a roll-your-own patch for std::to_string() to work properly with doubles on an old compiler

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, tostring

I'm patching up security flaws in a 15-20 year old system that hasn't been maintained for 10 years.  As such, most of my "patches" are really work arounds and kludges because a real solution would erode the integrity of a working (if insecure) system.  One of the "patches" I applied was related to my old compiler [not being able to find `to_string()` within `std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g), which works pretty well, but not perfectly.

Somewhere in these thousands of lines of code, I try to convert a `double` using `patch::to_string()`, and it fails to compile with the following error:

```
    g++  -o main -Wall -g -Wextra -pedantic main.o veracodefunctions.o
main.o: In function `main':
/home/(omited for privacy)/2_Test/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > patch::to_string<double>(double const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
clearmake: Error: Build script failed for "main"
```

Below is the original implementation of the patch I used, which I got from [the above Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20861692/3633538), and should work:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

namespace patch
{
    template < typename T > std::string to_string( const T& n )
    {
        std::ostringstream stm ;
        stm << n ;
        return stm.str() ;
    }
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << patch::to_string(1234) << '\n' << patch::to_string(1234.56) << '\n' ;
}
```

The patch by [cMinor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265519/cminor) has this `main()` at the bottom of it that is supposed to illustrate that it works with both `int` and `double` values, but for some reason mine only works with `int`, and not with `double`.  Here is my implementation:

patch.h:

```
8 #include <string>
...
25 namespace patch
26 {
27    template < typename T > std::string to_string( const T& n );
28 }
```

patch.cpp:

```
6 #include <string>
7 #include <sstream>
8 #include <stdexcept>
9 #include "patch.h"
...
41 namespace patch
42 {
43    template < typename T > std::string to_string( const T& n )
44    {
45       std::ostringstream stm;
46       stm << n;
47       return stm.str();
48    }
49 }
```

main.cpp:

```
2 #include <iostream>
3 #include "patch.h"
4 
5 int main () {
6 
7    std::cout << "\"12345\" to string is: " << patch::to_string(12345) << std::endl;
8    std::cout << "\"12.345\" to string is: " << patch::to_string(12.345) << std::endl;
9    return 0;
10 
11 }
```

And just so you don't have to scroll, here is the compile error again:

```
    g++  -o main -Wall -g -Wextra -pedantic main.o veracodefunctions.o
main.o: In function `main':
/home/(omited for privacy)/2_Test/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > patch::to_string<double>(double const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
clearmake: Error: Build script failed for "main"
```

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: Template definitions must be in the header file, not the source file.

Comment: @galinette Can you be a little more specific with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only **declared** `to_string()` in the header, and **defined** it in the cpp files. While this is the normal way with non-template functions, this is incorrect with templates. You need to place the **definition** (the actual implementation) in the .h header file, not in the .cpp file.

patch.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace patch
{

    template < typename T > std::string to_string( const T& n )
    {
       std::ostringstream stm;
       stm << n;
       return stm.str();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought I did. Could you be a little more specific? I don't fully understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Ah, so the whole definition should be in the .h, and there should be nothing in the .cpp file?

Comment: I'll try this now, and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The compiler needs to have the full body in every translation unit when you use templates.

Comment: It compiles now! Thank you. I find it odd though that it would compile and run if I was only using `to_string()` on an `int`, but not on a `double`.  Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: That's actually strange and not standard. The compiler may somehow manage to reduce the template to a non-template if only one type is used?

Comment: Kinda bizarre, huh? Anyway, thank you again. Glad to learn something today. Enjoy the day!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76501/discussion-between-galinette-and-makenbaccon).

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a header type, the compiler will create a new class for that instantiation. IF the implementation of your function is not in a header, it will not be accessible at compile time which is why you are getting a linker error.

This question has been mostly answered here:
[Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: I'll have to read that over. Thank you very much!