# How can I use std::begin and std::end without C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, g++, std

I'm trying to write code that will compile for [POJ](http://poj.org). POJ doesn't use C++11 so I can't use really basic STL functions like `std::to_string`, `std::begin`, or `std::end`. I looked around and found [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g) inquiring about `std::to_string`. To get `std::to_string` code to compile with a bare `g++ myfile.cpp` command, a user suggested this patch, which works nicely:

```
namespace patch
{
    template < typename T > std::string to_string( const T& n )
    {
        std::ostringstream stm ;
        stm << n ;
        return stm.str() ;
    }
}
```

I want to do the same thing for `std::begin`, `std::end`, and `std::stoi`, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm quite unfamiliar with the STL. I just want my working C++11 code to compile with either MS-VC++6.0 or G++ *without any flags, etc.* How can I do this?

Comment: The short answer is "you can't". Those are C++ 11 features and you need C++ 11 to do it (or C++ 14). You CAN do as the patch above did and implement your own implementation of std::begin, etc. But you have to write it in whatever version of C++ you have.

Comment: @mrunion, why so sad? Of course you can do std::begin, std::end and std::stoi in C++03.

Comment: Well you wouldn't be able to put them in `namespace std` itself, but you could work around that.

Comment: Look in the headers provided by modern VS for the code of these functions and figure out how to adapt it. Basically you need one version which calls `c.begin()` but another version specialized for arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty straightforward.
For instance, here is std::begin:

```
template <typename C>
typename C::iterator my_begin(C& ctr) { return ctr.begin(); }

template <typename C>
typename C::const_iterator my_begin(const C& ctr) { return ctr.begin(); }

template <typename C, size_t sz>
C* my_begin(C (&ctr)[sz]) { return &ctr[0]; } 

template <typename C, size_t sz>
const C* my_begin(const C (&ctr)[sz]) { return &ctr[0]; }
```

Comment: What about arrays? That is the whole point why these functions are needed.

Comment: @dyp, sure thing. Added it, was typing in a hurry.

Comment: And a `const_iterator` / `const C&` overload. And another overload for arrays.

Comment: Naming it `my_begin` kinda defeats the purpose of having it at all

Comment: Thanks for giving me an idea of how to do it. Now I just need to figure out `std::stoi`.

Comment: @imreal, once you start hacking, nothign stops you from actually naming it begin and putting into std::. Prohibited, but whatever.

Comment: The last overload isn't necessary. For const arrays, `C` will be deduced to be `const` in the third overload, and it is more specialized than the other two.

Comment: @gragas: `stoi` is just an `istringstream s(input); s >> i` with some error handling.

Answer (score 0):

boost::lexical_cast can do the same job as that of to_string and it does not require C++11. Below is a simple example:

```
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(12345)
```

Comment: The whole point is this must compile with vanilla MS-VC++6.0 or G++. By vanilla I mean **no flags, no options, no extras.** This means I cannot use boost.