# Cygwin: g++ 5.2: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cygwin

The following simple program can't be compiled in cygwin with gcc

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::to_string(4) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Command line:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x to_string.cc
```

Error:

```
to_string.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
to_string.cc:6:16: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
   std::cout << std::to_string(4) << std::endl;
```

G++ version:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.2.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The same code can be compiled in Ubuntu.

Is it possible at all compile this code with cygwin or I need to write a workaround?

Comment: You may need to use `-std=c++11` instead of `-std=c++0x`

Comment: @NathanOliver the same result.

Comment: Have you checked which `<string>` header is used?

Comment: @SimonKraemer What exactly do you mean and how can I do it?

Comment: Try `g++ -E -x c++ -std=c++11 - -v < /dev/null`

Comment: @SimonKraemer And what should I see (except obvious `to_string`)?

Comment: @Alex This will print the include directories in the order they are searched. You should be able to see if you are including a C++11 compliant version of `<string>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94102/discussion-between-alex-and-simon-kraemer).

Answer (score -2):

You are mixing gcc and g++ here

To quote `Mike F`: "The probably most important difference in their defaults is which libraries they link against automatically."

[What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: He obviously uses g++ to compile the file, see his command line. So this should be totally fine.

Comment: @leemes Why don't you check the times on my answer and Alex's edit?

Comment: The command line uses `g++` before the edit...