# to_string() not declared in gnustl_static

Tags: android, string, c++11, java-native-interface, gnu

This code will give an error message "to_string was not declared in this scope"

```
#include <jni.h>
#inlcude <string>
#include <android/log.h>
using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_package_activity_method
(JNIEnv *env, jobject classObject,jdouble number) {
  String string= to_string(number);
   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "JNI","The number is: %s,string);
  return;
}
```

if trace the header file I can find these in string.h -> basic_string.h

```
inline string
to_string(double __val)
{
  const int __n = 
   __gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits<double>::__max_exponent10 + 20;
  return __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<string>(&std::vsnprintf, __n,
                   "%f", __val);
}
```

So it was declared after all...

I can fix the problem by writing my own version of to_string

```
String to_string(double number){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();  }
```

or change
 -DANDROID_STL to c++_static

but what I am trying to understand it which part of the code obscure the to_string method in gnustl from being seen.

Comment: Don't forget that it's in the `std` namespace. Perhaps you need to do `std::to_string`?

Comment: corrected but that is not the problem

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a copy-paste (as text) of the *complete* and *full* error output? Including any possible informational notes.

Comment: /home/package/app/src/main/cpp/method.cpp: In function 'jboolean Java_com_package_activity_method(JNIEnv*, jobject, jdouble)':
/home/package/app/src/main/cpp/method.cpp:67:36: error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope
     String string= to_string(number);

Comment: `std::to_string` simply isn't available in the gnustl version that came with the NDK (see https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/82). And since gnustl has been deprecated since NDK r17 and removed altogether since NDK r18 it will never be added. You should be using libc++ instead (i.e. c++_static or c++_shared).

Comment: As for why the function is not visible to your code, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517938/glibcxx-use-c99-is-not-defined-to-wstring-not-available

Comment: there are other compiled libraries still rely on gnustl before I convert all of them still I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand from the other post this is why to_string is not include in GNUSTL

in c++config.h line 1240 the following line is commented out and therefore _GLIBCXX_USE_C99 is not defined

```
/* Define if C99 functions or macros from <wchar.h>, <math.h>, <complex.h>,
   <stdio.h>, and <stdlib.h> can be used or exposed. */
/* #undef _GLIBCXX_USE_C99 */
```

and this condition is checked at basic_string.h :2812

```
#if ((__cplusplus >= 201103L) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99) \
    && !defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF))
```

but why is it dong that I don't understand aren't stdio stdlib are some of the basic c libraries?

Comment: _"but why is it dong that"_ Read the answer to the question I linked to in one of my comments on your question.