# std::to_string not a member in C++11 using CygWin

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++11

I have the following code...

```
// My.h
#include <string>
....

// My.cpp
#include "My.h"
...
errMsg = "X value [too low]: " + std::to_string(xInVal);
```

But when I compile like...

```
//setup.py
extra_compile_args =['-std=c++11']

//console output
gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.3-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.3-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.3-1.x86_64/src/Python-3.4.3=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.3-1 -I./My -c ./My.cpp -o build/temp.cygwin-2.2.1-x86_64-3.4/./My.o -std=c++11
```

I get the following error....

```
 error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
   errMsg = "X value [too low]: " + std::to_string(xInVal);
```

What am I missing how do I use to_string in this way?

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g

Comment: What version of GCC are you using (`gcc --version`) ?

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work even on Cygwin GCC 5.2.0 + stdlibc++ 5.2.0. I was very surprised. @Jackie you might implement it yourself, it's not a big deal, or to switch to another Windows toolchain: MSYS + MinGW-w64 (have it fixed), Visual studio (it is not that bad as it used to be and they have standalone toolchain now, that is without IDE), Clang/C2 (clang frontend + microsoft codegen), Intel etc. The only problem is if your app uses something like autotools or Unix-specific headers/libs.

Comment: @Drop Thanks I tried to look up how to patch it but I am not having much luck. If I fall back to a Unix VM it should work ok right (or at least not have these problems). Guess I will have to bring myself to learn one of those other toolchains.

Answer (score 0):

From the CYGWIN headers, it looks like for C++11 these are not defined unless `_GLIBCXX_USE_C99` is defined  They are enclosed in this if:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99)
```

I tried defining `_GLIBCXX_USE_C99` but that didn't work for my project.  You can try defining it before you use the string header.

I recently had a similar issue with C++11 on CYGWIN related to `__STRICT_ANSI__`