# Code::Blocks c++ 11 flags

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

I need to perform Circular Right Shift in my program and I am doing it the following way :-

```
int a = 425;

int q = a / 10;
int r = a % 10;

string t = to_string(q);
string s = to_string(r);

int newnum = stoi(s+t);

cout<<newnum<<endl;
```

It is working on my terminal after I include -std=c++11 flag but when i tried it in Code::Blocks it wasn't working so i checked this
 Settings -> Compiler ->"Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]"
 but it is still giving me the error "to_string was not declared in this scope".

Comment: Have you included `#include<string>` and added proper `namespace std`?

Comment: which version of codeblocks, and are you using the default compiler it came with

Comment: probably duplicate of [to_string is not a member of std, says so g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g)

Comment: @M.M i am using Code::Blocks 13.12 and the default compiler is GNU-GCC

Comment: ok, follow the link I just posted. I would recommed using the most recent version of C::B, and also replacing the compiler with [mingw-w64](http://www.mingw-w64.org) which is much more up to date than the packaged compiler