# to_string() not working in CodeBlocks 16.01

Tags: c++

I can't use to_string() in CodeBlocks. I ticked the box to use compiler flag **-std=c++11**.

I want my program to be able to run something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    cout << to_string(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Any solutions?

**EDIT**:

I get error message: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope.

I am using the GNU GCC Compiler that came with the installation of CodeBlocks.

Comment: add #include <string> . http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/

Comment: I edited now and added #include <string>, still the same problem.

Comment: Define *"can't use"* - what happens? what error messages do you receive?

Comment: Also which compiler are you using?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/xNz6u3). Include the *exact* error message, if any, from your toolchain, in your question.

Comment: Is it the builtin g++ or some potentially stupid compiler?

Comment: I edited it now, see again

Comment: So, does anyone have any solutions ?

Comment: [to_string is not a member of std, says g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-g/12975602#12975602)

Comment: @George, that solved the problem for me. Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for editing the question to get it into an answerable form and for confirming that the answer provided in the other question helped.