# error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope in Windows using cmd

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, g++, mingw

I'm trying compile this code in cmd:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n = 24;
    string s = to_string(n);
    cout<<s;
}
```

I found in another qestions, that I should use this command:

> g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp

but I get error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:7:24: error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope
  string s = to_string(n);
                        ^
```

I have latest g++ compiler for Windows v. 5.3.0. I used [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/) installer for MinGW.
I tried solve in [to_string is not a member of std, says g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-g), but this patch doesn't work.

How can I compile this code in command line in Windows?

Comment: Is this the real code, that you use for the test?

Comment: yes, it's exactly the same code.

Comment: this issue looks similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-g

Comment: Maybe it's the compiler version. I can compile this perfectly fine with my g++ 5.4 (Linux), it can be compiled with g++ 5.2 (via cppreference.com), but cannot be compiled with ideone.com with g++ 5.1 (only with C++14 option can, it probably uses a newer version). Even gcc 4.7 can compile this, it really seems like a compiler issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [to\_string is not a member of std, says g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-g)

Comment: BTW, consider using this mingw distro https://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Comment: @Grisha this distro is working thank you very much. Btw its very weird that this issue disapears.