# How to show score on screen C++ SDL

Tags: c++, class, variables, sdl

I am programming Pac-man in C++ SDL and I want to show the score on the screen.

My score is a class:

```
entite.score += 10;

entite.scoreTotal += 10;
```

and then I call them to the main.

To write a texte I use this function :

```
afficherTexte(screenSurface, "Score", 255, 255, 255, "./Polices/crackman.ttf", 30, 30, 540);
```

but I don't know how to show on screen variables of the type class.

Comment: Are you print the score in orthographic projection?

Comment: Vague. To my understanding you can print static text, but you don't know how to do that with variable value, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `int` to a `string` in order to call it in that method.

Here's an example of the conversion just using `cout`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    std::string y;
    y  = std::to_string(x);
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is `42`

However you may run into a MinGW or G++ bug while compiling that, fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-g-mingw).

When you call `afficherTexte(screenSurface, "Score", 255, 255, 255, "./Polices/crackman.ttf", 30, 30, 540);` just replace the `Score` with `y`, as I called it in my example.