# Eclipse C++ Linux "to_string was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, scope, eclipse-cdt

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string Person::toSimpleString(){

     return getFirstName() + " " + getLastName() + ", Age " + to_string(5);
}
```

All of my strings are working fine but I cannot get the to_string function to work at all. Eclipse keeps telling me it is out of scope. Wht

Comment: Is Eclipse giving you a codan warning, or are you getting a compile error?

Comment: You need to compile with C++11 support, in order to use std::to_string

Comment: Do you have C++11 enabled in your compile options?

Comment: How do I enable c++11?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: If you use MINGW it probably won´t work [see this GCC issue](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59076). Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521617/c11-to-string-function-where) too.

Answer (score -2):

Does `#include <string>` need to be `#include <string.h>`?

I think you might be missing the ".h"

Comment: No, [string and string.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257665/difference-between-string-and-string-h) are different.

Comment: Beware of the subtle difference, in C++ `#include <string>` is including the string class from the standard library, and **not** the standard C string manipulation functions (that can be included with `<cstring>` in C++, or with `<string.h>` in both languages)

Comment: Ahh wow, I didn't know there was a difference. Thanks for the corrections.